# Filtering Twitter feeds - removing @ posts from the feed

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to filter Twitter feeds so that I do not see the @replies of a given user?

For example, I [generally] do not want to see the "@reply thanks"-type messages from companies to followers.

Comment: Duplicate of a question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619773/filter-out-replies-in-a-twitter-feed

Comment: @Ciaran - thanks for the link, though those are programmatic solutions rather than settings inside Twitter or a Twitter viewer :-\ ..which is what I'm looking for here if possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I don't think you can see those replies in your timeline unless you follow both users unless they precede `@` with a next character. You may want to check @support

> ".@twitter the whale is huge"

The above is just an update with a mention as opposed to a reply.

You can use a userscript such as [Tweetfilter](http://tweetfilter.netne.net/) and choose filter all replies.

Comment: I mean when looking at a given user's timeline